# jQuery animations: Having issues undoing an animation of a fixed div

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/HLw9U/

When the document loads, the footer slides to the top.

I want it so that when you click the document, the footer slides back down to the bottom.

But alas, it just stays at the top.

What trickery is going on here?

EDIT: added code

```
function slide_footer_to_top(){
    $j(".footer").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        bottom: "20%",
    }, 200, function(){
        // finished
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: "0%",
    }, 600, function(){
        // finished
    });
}

function slide_footer_to_bottom(){
    $j(".footer").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        top: "inherit",
        bottom: "100%",
    }, 300, function(){
        // finished
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: "inherit",
        bottom: "0%",
    }, 500, function(){
        // finished
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the top and bottom values at the same time - the top value overrides any bottom value and the div stays on top. Try something like:

```
function slide_footer_to_bottom(){
    $j(".footer").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        top: "90%",
    }, 300, function(){
        // finished
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: "90%",
    }, 500, function(){
        // finished
    });
```

or unset the top value:

```
$j(".footer").css('top', '');
```